# Can we use One XA Resource and Two Non XA resource in our repository layer

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Can we use combination of xa and non xa resource in same repository class.
If we can, can anybody please explain how it will behave and how the transaction will work. Currently we are using 2 xa resource and 2 non xa resource in our repository. We are using glassfish and eclipselink.
Is there any issue in approach.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use multiple local(=non-XA) data sources in a single transaction but you can combine multiple XA resources in a global transaction or let a non-XA resource participate in a global transaction (with 1 XA datasource) (see LLR [1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/jta/llr.html) / [2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/jdbc_admin/jdbc_datasources.html#llr)).

Things you can consider:
Disable transaction support for one non-XA data source  or wrap them in an EJB with `@TransactionAttribute(NOT_SUPPORTED)` to disable transactions. You can also orchestrate transactions manually but that can become quite a hassle.

From the [GlassFish 3 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beanm/index.html): (older version but same applies for newer versions)

> Transaction Scope A local transaction involves only one non-XA
>   resource and requires that all participating application components
>   execute within one process. Local transaction optimization is specific
>   to the resource manager and is transparent to the Java EE application.
>
> In the GlassFish Server, a JDBC resource is non-XA if it meets either
>   of the following criteria:
>
> - In the JDBC connection pool configuration, the DataSource class does
>     not implement the javax.sql.XADataSource interface.
> - The Resource Type setting is not set to javax.sql.XADataSource.
>
> A transaction remains local if the following conditions remain true:
>
> - One and only one non-XA resource is used. If any additional non-XA
>     resource is used, the transaction is aborted.
> - No transaction importing or exporting occurs.
>
> Transactions that involve multiple resources or multiple participant
>   processes are distributed or global transactions. A global transaction
>   can involve one non-XA resource if last agent optimization is enabled.
>   Otherwise, all resourced must be XA. The use-last-agent-optimization
>   property is set to true by default. For details about how to set this
>   property, see Configuring the Transaction Service.
>
> If only one XA resource is used in a transaction, one-phase commit
>   occurs, otherwise the transaction is coordinated with a two-phase
>   commit protocol.